# Batch rename program

Tags: batch

I have a master directory called `KARAOKI`, in it are folders for artists, and in those folders are all their songs.  I need to insert the folder name in front of each song in that folder so I can load it into a Karaoke master file

For example, the below filename needs to look like:  `Elvis Presley - Are You Lonesome Tonight`:

- Folder Name: `Elvis Presley` 
   Title Name: `Are You Lonesome Tonight`

Comment: Please edit your question to include examples of the filenames you'd like to change and what you'd like to change them to.

Answer (score 1):

PowerShell:

```powershell
$Root = 'C:\KARAOKI'
$Songs = Get-ChildItem $Root -File -Recurse
$Songs | Rename-Item -NewName {'{0} - {1}' -f $_.Directory.Name, $_.Name}
```

[Get-CHildItem](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem?view=powershell-7)
[Rename-Item](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/rename-item?view=powershell-7)
[-f format operator](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7#format-operator--f)

Comment: I think this is above my head.  Just wanted a batch stream to rename this songs to include the folder name.  I'm not sure what this answer is.  Is it complete.  I am a novice.

Comment: Yes, it's complete. You just need to edit the path 'C:\KARAOKI' if necessary. It will rename every file it finds in sub-folders of the `$root` folder. You weren't any more specific about file extension or type. That can easily be added.

Answer (score 0):

```bat
@echo off && setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

cd /d "%~dp0" && for /f tokens^=* %%i in ('dir /s /b /a:d')do for /f tokens^=* %%I in ('
dir /a:-d /b "%%~i"')do if not "%%~nxI" == "%~nx0" ren "%%~dpni\%%~nxI" "%%~ni - %%~nxI"

endlocal & goto :EOF
```

**1)** Try using **`delayed expansion`** for your variables:

```bat
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
```

**2)** Go to folder where bat (I suppose) will run/work == Master Drive:\Master-Folder:

```bat
cd /d "%~dp0"
```

**3)** Use a **`for`** loop to running in all sub folder recursively only, folder == **`%%~i`**:

```bat
for /f tokens^=* %%i in ('dir /s /b /a:d')do...
```

**4)** Use a 2nd **`for`** in current folder (**`%%~i`**) for get/list any file (**`%%~I`**) in current folder:

```bat
for /f tokens^=* %%i in ('dir /s /b /a:d')do for /f tokens^=* %%I in ('
dir /a:-d /b "%%~i"')do...
```

**5)** Use expanded variable **`%%~nxi`**,  **`%%~ni`**, **`%~nx0`**,  **`%%~dpni\%%~nxI`** and **`%%~xi`**, according to the layout name needs:

```bat
%~nx0   ==    Name + Extension file.bat %0         ==    Q1537358.cmd

%%~ni   ==    Name Folder in loop %%i              ==    Are You Lonesome Tonight.ext

%%~nxI  ==    Name + Extension file in loop %%I    ==    Elvis Presley

%%~dpni ==    Drive + Path Name file in loop %%i   ==    D:\KARAOKI

%%~nxI  ==    Name Folder in loop %%I              ==    KARAOKI
```

**6)** Use **`if`** to compare the current name\extension file is not the same to your current bat/cmd file before try to rename any file:

```bat
if not "%%~nxI" == "%~nx0"
```

**7)** Use **`if`** to compare the current name\extension file is not the same to your current bat/cmd file before try to rename any file:

**8)** Rename your file with this layout name in loop variable expanded:

```bat
ren "%%~dpni\%%~nxI" "%%~ni - %%~nxI"
ren "D:\KARAOKI\Elvis Presley\Are You Lonesome Tonight.ext" "Elvis Presley - Are You Lonesome Tonight.ext"
```

**Obs.:** This presuming that you will to save this bat file and run them in the same **`Drive:\Folder`** where your master directory **`\KARAOKI`** is/are...

```bat
C:\KARAOKI or D:\KARAOKI or E:\KARAOKI...
```

**For command line help, you can use `/?`:**

```bat
Ren /?, For /?,CD /?, Setlocal /?, Endlocal /?, Goto /?, Setlocal /?, Endlocal /?, if /?
```

**On the internet, you can get more help on:**

- **[Cd](https://ss64.com/nt/cd.html)**
- **[Dir](https://ss64.com/nt/dir.html)**
- **[Ren](https://ss64.com/nt/ren.html)**
- **[For /f](https://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html)**
- **[Setlocal](https://ss64.com/nt/setlocal.html)**
- **[Endlocal](https://ss64.com/nt/endlocal.html)**
- **[Goto :EOF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37515901/where-does-goto-eof-return-to)**
- **[EnableDelayedExpansion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30282784/variables-are-not-behaving-as-expected/30284028#30284028)**
- **[If, Else If, Else, If Defined, Errorlevel ...](https://ss64.com/nt/if.html)**

<sub>So sorry my limited English</sub>

Answer (score 0):

For simple renaming (if it only depends on the name of the file, and maybe some number/letters sequence) I use a simple old but nice freeware software called "Lupas Rename 2000". Since this needs to navigate also to the parent folder to get the name I am not sure It will work in your case. Anyways, you can find it here: http://rename.lupasfreeware.org/download.php

For your problem, I guess you need more elaborated tools. The one from Keith Miller seems quite clean and effective if you have access to PowerShell.